# convert/repack 16 bytes/bytearray with 1 significant bit into byte with all significant bits in python3

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, byte, bit, pack

How I can repack 8 bytes or bytearray with 1 significant bit into byte with hex value in python3 for example:

```
  bytearray = [b'\x01', b'\x01', b'\x01', b'\x01',
               b'\x01', b'\x01', b'\x01', b'\x01']
```

converts to:

```
byte = b'\ff\
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
bits = [b'\x01', b'\x00', b'\x01', b'\x01',
        b'\x01', b'\x01', b'\x01', b'\x00']  # 1011 1110 -> 0xbe

int_val = sum(bit[0] << 7-i for i, bit in enumerate(bits))
byte = bytes([int_val])
print(byte)
# b'\xbe'
```

As `bytes` objects behave like sequences of integer, we get:

```
b'\x01`[0]
# 1
```

We shift the bit values to the left: for the first one in the list, `i` will be 0, so it gets shifted by 7 positions, and so on. Then we sum these values to get the numerical value of your byte.

`bytes()` accepts sequences of integers, so we pass it a list with our byte value as only item.